# Division by 8 with SHR instruction

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

> Write a complete assembly program to read 8 digits, each digit separated by a single space from the keyboard (use single key input function). Convert them from character to numbers and calculate the average, lowest and highest score and display them on the screen.
>
> Hint: Subtract `30h` from each character to get actual digit. Before display, add `30h` to each digit. For division operation, use appropriate shift instruction.

Average is showing the wrong answer! Where did I do wrong? Plz help me understand division by SRH instruction.

```
Include emu8086.inc
.model small
.stack 100h  
.data

 
.code
 mov bh,0
 mov bl,9  
 mov ah,1
 mov dh,0
 mov cx,0    
 
 input:    
 int 21H   
 putc 20h
 sub al,30h
 inc cx
 add dh,al
 cmp al,bh
 JA _max
 cmp al,bl
 JB _min  
 cmp cx,8
 JB input
 
 
 print:
 mov ah,2 
 printn
 mov dl,bh 
 add dl,30h
 printn "Max: "
 int 21h
   
 printn
 mov dl,bl
 add dl,30h
 printn "Min: "
 int 21h 
 
 AND dh, 0FH
 
 mov Cl,3
 shr dh,cl
 
 or dh,30H
 
 printn
 mov dl,dh
 printn "Avg: "
 int 21h 
 
 exit:
 mov ah,4ch
 int 21h
 
 _max:
 mov bh,al 
 cmp al,bl
 JB _min  
 cmp cx,8
 jae print
 jb input
 
 _min:
 mov bl,al
 cmp cx,10
 jae print
 jb input
```

Comment: It's `SHR` not `SRH`, but that is fine in the code. Yes, you can divide by 8 like that. The problem is you should be dividing the sum. Also, the sum should not be masked to 4 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing by 8 of an unsigned number is the same as shifting the number 3 times to the right. In 8086 programming we need to put the shift count in the `CL` register before executing the `shr` instruction. Because you have placed the sum (that you want to divide) in the `DH` register and you want to display the average (result from the division) from the `DL` register (requested by the DOS.PrintChar function), you can do this in just 2 instructions:

```
mov cl, 11   ; 11 = 3 (is divide DH by 8) + 8 (is move DH to DL)
shr dx, cl
```

---

> ```
> _min:
> mov bl,al
> cmp cx,10
> ```

Just like the *_max*, this *_min* should be using `cmp cx, 8`.

Better still, you should probably not duplicate that much code! Below code uses the opposite conditions and keeps everything nicely together:

```
.code
  mov bx, 9    ; BH=0 is Max, BL=9 is Min
  xor dx, dx   ; DH=0 is Sum, DL=0 is Count
input:
  mov ah, 01h  ; DOS.GetCharacter
  int 21h  
  putc 20h
  sub al, 30h
  add dh, al   ; Add to Sum DH
  cmp al, bh
  jbe NotMax
  mov bh, al   ; Set new max BH
NotMax:
  cmp al, bl
  jae NotMin
  mov bl, al   ; Set new Min BL
NotMin:
  inc dx       ; Increment Count DL
  cmp dl, 8
  jb input
```

Don't forget to add some meaningful comments in your programs so people can quickly understand what you have written.

Comment: @zx485: That's what I thought at first, but then realized it was intentionally shifting 8 + 3 = 11 to emulate `mov dl,dh` / `shr dl,3`.  (Which would be faster on CPUs without a barrel shifter, so every count takes a clock.  But for code-size this is good.  And yes I know shr dl,3 without using CL needs 186 or later.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thank you for this explanation. I underestimated the cleverness of the optimized code. Pardon me.